# how can i use h2o stacked autoencoder for clustering

Tags: deep-learning, h2o, autoencoder

I’m new in deep learning and I’m trying to perform clustering on some cancer data to get patient subtypes, I found that autoencoders are the unsupervised learning algorithm that can help me, and I want to try h2o stacked autoencoder to get my clusters, my question is there anyone know where to find an implementation example. Or give me some suggestions.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question: How will you be using it? Have you researched the topic? Is there [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepLearningBooklet.pdf) that you werent able to follow in a specific way?

Comment: i want to use stacked autoencoder for dimensionality reduction after that to apply kmeans clustering on the compressed data to get clusters, I have looked a little into the topic, but still do not know how to use it (h2o stacked autoencoder) , so I'm looking for documentation or exemples that can help me to do this. sorry about my poor english

Comment: No problem - Were you able to follow the document posted by @kevin-katzke? If you have a specific question, with a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), theres obviously one person here who has some knowledge

Answer (score 1):

The manual [Deep Learning with H2O](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepLearningBooklet.pdf) should be helpful. Autoencoders are explained starting from page 43 with an implementation in bot `R` and `Python`. For Stacking in H2O refer to [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/runit_deeplearning_stacked_autoencoder_large.R) of how to create a stacked autoencoder using the **h2o** R package and the `h2o.deeplearning()` function.

The [H2O Deep Learning in R Tutorial](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/ledell/sldm4-h2o/blob/master/sldm4-deeplearning-h2o.html) that provides more background on Deep Learning in H2O, including how to use an autoencoder for unsupervised pretraining.

There are more H2O code tutorials in the [h2oai/h2o-tutorials](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials) GitHub repo, or you can often find code examples in the `tests` directories of the H2O codebase (I found the stacked autoencoder example by searching for "stacked autoencoder" in the [h2oai/h2o-3](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stacked+autoencoder&type=) repository on GitHub, for example).